# Prove that the vectors Av and Aw are independent if v and w are independent column vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Prove that the vectors A$\mathbf{v}$ and A$\mathbf{w}$ are independent, if $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are independent column vectors in $\Bbb{R}^3$, and A is an invertible 3 x 3 matrix.

Wondering if my proof is alright, please check:

If $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ are independent column vectors, then r$\mathbf{v}$ + s$\mathbf{w}$  = 0, and r = 0, s = 0.

A (r$\mathbf{v}$ + s$\mathbf{w}$) = 0

r(A$\mathbf{v}$) + s(A$\mathbf{w}$) = 0

Since both r and s equal 0, it follows that A$\mathbf{v}$ and A$\mathbf{w}$ are also independent column vectors.

My question: Why does the problem mention that A is an "invertible" 3 x 3 matrix? It seems to me that it doesn't really matter if A is invertible?

Similarly, let $\mathbf{v}_1$, $\mathbf{v}_2$, ... , $\mathbf{v}_k$ be independent column vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and let C be an invertible n x n matrix. Prove that the vectors C$\mathbf{v}_1$, C$\mathbf{v}_2$, ... , C$\mathbf{v}_k$ are independent.

I'm thinking about applying the same method as above to prove this similar problem. Is it okay? But once again, why does the problem have to say "let C be an INVERTIBLE n x n matrix"? Why must invertible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *absolutely* matters that $A$ be invertible. For example, if $A$ is the zero matrix, then $A\vec v$ and $A\vec w$ are definitely not independent, regardless of $\vec v$ and $\vec w.$

You also seem to be misunderstanding what "independent" means. Since $\vec v$ and $\vec w$ are independent, then **if** we know that $r\vec v+s\vec w=\vec 0,$ we can conclude that $r=s=0.$ To show that $A\vec v$ and $A\vec w$ are independent, you begin by assuming that $$rA\vec v+sA\vec w=\vec 0,$$ and then *prove* that $r=s=0.$ As you've already noticed, $rA\vec v+sA\vec w=A\left(r\vec v+s\vec w\right),$ so by assumption, we can conclude that $$A\left(r\vec v+s\vec w\right)=\vec 0.$$ **If** we can prove that $r\vec v+s\vec w=\vec 0,$ then it will follow that $r=s=0,$ as desired. In order to prove that, though, we have to know that $A$ is invertible. When $A$ is *not* invertible, there will be vectors $\vec u$ such that $A\vec u=\vec 0$ and $\vec u\neq \vec 0,$ so it would be entirely possible to have $A\left(r\vec v+s\vec w\right)=\vec 0,$ but $r\vec v+s\vec w\neq \vec 0,$ so that $r$ and $s$ are *not* both $0$, and so $A\vec v$ and $A\vec w$ would *not* be independent.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the order. You must start with $$r(A\mathbf{v}) + s(A\mathbf{w}) = 0$$
Then since $A$ is linear you have $$ A(r\mathbf{v} + s\mathbf{w}) = 0$$
Now since $A$ is invertible the only vector which maps to $0$ is $0$, so we have:
$$r\mathbf{v} + s\mathbf{w} = 0$$
Now since $\mathbf{v},\mathbf{w}$ are linear independent we have $r=s=0$.
So  $A\mathbf{v},A\mathbf{w}$ are also LI

Answer (score 0):

Since $A = [\vec{v} \mid \vec{w}]$ and $\vec{v}, \vec{w}$ are linearly independent, it follows that $\textbf{det}(A) \not = 0$ which implies $A$ is invertible. This means the kernel is trivial i.e $A \vec{z} = \vec{0} \iff \vec{z} = \vec{0}$. Now the string of inequalities follow.

$$ \lambda_1 A\vec{v} + \lambda_2 A \vec{w} = 0 \iff A( \lambda_1 \vec{v} + \lambda_2 \vec{w} ) = 0 \iff \lambda_1 \vec{v} + \lambda_2 \vec{w} = 0$$